# Choosing a footprint in KiCad?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad, footprint

So, let's say I'm composing a schematic for a circuit I'm designing in `KiCad`, and... done.

I now have to to choose a footprint for my components.  How does one identify the appropriate footprint for a given component?  I open up `CvPCB` to an utterly daunting array of possible footprints, none of which seem to be referenced anywhere else in creation- google knows nothing of the footprint "names" seen in KiCad (that I can tell.)

I need the dimensions of a standard DIP pin - I have a component that can fit in [this](http://www.radioshack.com/product/index.jsp?productId=2062602) for example (yes, it wil tolerate heat :P)

I *am* perfectly happy to create my own parts with my handy dandy digital caliper!  It'd just be nice if that massive library that comes with KiCad can actually do something.

Comment: What are typical names of the footprints you see in KiCad? What does the datasheet of your parts say about their footprints?

Comment: That library is quite a mess, my advice is: start building your own and keep it safe and sound. Some parts of it are good anyway. About the caliber, keep in mind that every datasheet includes a "landing pattern" that you should respect. I had to use the caliber only for odd shaped components, to be sure the clearence between them was enough.

Answer (score 3):

In CvPcb there is the "View selected footprint" in the top toolbar.

[image: CvPcb-1]

Once you press that button, a new window pops-up where you can see your footprint.

[image: CvPcb-2]

This new window allows you see the component and has a grid from which you can find out the size of your component. This grid is also selectable by right-clicking the grid and choosing whatever grid you want from "Grid Select" option.

[image: CvPcb-3]

If you mouse-hover on one pin, on the bottom of the window there are X-Y coordinates from which you can tell the distance between the pins. This one, from the example, has **5.08mm * 2 = 10.16mm = 0.4inches** distance between the pins.