# Does footprint matter when selecting a part in Kicad?

Tags: pcb-design, circuit-design, kicad, footprint

When designing a circuit schematic in Kicad, does it matter what footprint or package is listed in the part name?

This is similar to [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/124144/choosing-a-footprint-in-kicad), but I'm more confused about the naming scheme shown in Kicad's part selector in the schematic editor. As I understand Kicad's workflow, you design the circuit first and then specify footprints later when designing the pcb.

I want to place a n-channel mosfet, and I know the physical part needs to be in the 3-pin DPAK package size. When I go to select a mosfet in the schematic view, Kicad's part selector lists a lot of mosfets. Some specify no package, but a lot specify explicit packages like "SO-8" or "SOT-143". I don't see any listing "DPAK". Is DPAK not supported, or does the package listed in the parts selector not matter, and I can select the footprint later when designing the PCB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can select specific footprint later. And you can choose any footprint you like. Footprints that are assigned to some component are just filters or hints. If some MOSFET component has only "SO-8" specified, you can bypass that and choose completely different footprint.

In addition to that, DPAK and TO-252 is the same footprint. Sure there is TO-252 footprint in Kicad libraries.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't realize DPAK and TO-252 were synonymous. I see several listings for TO-252. Thanks.